# Являются ли узбекские названия городов иностранными или они освоены русским языком?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, топонимика

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняются ли названия городов в сочетании с родовым термином: в *г. Алмалыке*, в *г. Ахангаране* Ташкентской области Узбекистана? С одной стороны, такие названия обычно не склоняются, когда они употреблены в качестве приложения, но с другой, для освоенных русским языком названий склонение является нормальным. Являются ли узбекские наименования иностранными или они достаточно освоены русским языком?

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке склоняется всё, что может склоняться. Какой-нибудь Антанариву просклонять проблематично, а города на согласную или -а склоняются всегда.

*В г. Андижане 2005 г. произошёл мятеж, а в г. Оше в 2010 г. беспорядки.*

Comment: Я что-нибудь хорошее нельзя было найти для примера?

Comment: @М_Г я в своё время статьи именно по этим событиям писал, поэтому и вспомнились первыми.

Comment: Не знаете ли Вы какой-либо авторитетный источник, на который можно ссылаться?

Comment: @huyuffie http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=73

Comment: Судя по статье на грамота.ру: "Иноязычные названия, оканчивающиеся на согласный, обычно не склоняются в функции приложения: в городе Луисвилл, в городе Мобеж, в г. Ниамет, в провинции Зядинь, близ города Мэнстон. (Исключение составляют названия, давно заимствованные и освоенные русским языком: в городе Вашингтоне.)"

Т. е. в вышеописанном случае тоже не склоняются?

Comment: @huyuffie узбекские названия городов уже давно освоены языком.